# styling CSS3 grid items along an edge or line

Tags: css, grid-layout

I've been playing in Firefox DevEd which has grid layout enabled.

Over on codepen, Rachel has a bunch of examples, I'll refer to [this one](http://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/doxPda/). She has a different class for each grid item, and they could be (are) used for styling the items. But now I remove the padding from the .box class, and want to center all the text in the grid items that touch the left edge of the grid (one could imagine a much larger grid here, and layout that is responsive to different screen sizes). Obviously this could be done for this small example, by adding

```
.header, .sidebar, .footer { text-align: center; }
```

But in a larger and responsive layout, with different items potentially winding up on the left edge of the grid, is there a way of choosing the items that just happen to wind up touching the left edge, and centering their content?

```
WHAT-GOES-HERE { text-align: center; }
```

(not sure about the grid-layout tag... is a new one needed for CSS3 grid?)

Comment: Want exactly you want to do? Your question unclear, though.
Please you simple language to explain.

Comment: As a side note, it should be **justify-self** instead of text-align

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik The question is simple, and stated: is there a way of choosing the items that just happen to wind up touching the left edge, and centering their content?

Comment: @vals No, it should be text-align: center.  justify-self moves the grid item box, rather than formatting the content in the grid item box. The problem is the selection of which grid-items are on the left edge, not how to do the formatting.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible... Sorry